# Get DataFrame values from variable column

Tags: pandas

I would like to get series with values from column which name is variable and stored in 'COL'.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30, 40], 'B': [100, 200, 300, 400], 'COL': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']})
df
    A    B COL
0  10  100   A
1  20  200   B
2  30  300   A
3  40  400   B
```

What I need as a result:

```
     X
0   10
1  200
2   30
3  400
```

Comment: try `df.lookup`: `df['X'] = df.lookup(df.index,df['COL'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html), only necessary all values from `COL` exist in columns names:

```
df['X'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['COL'])
print (df)
   A   B COL   X
0  1  10   A   1
1  2  20   B  20
2  3  30   A   3
3  4  40   B  40
```

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your problem

```
df["X"]=df.apply(lambda x: x[x["COL"]],axis=1)
```